# Is it possible to use Feature Learning for Binary Text Classification?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, deep-learning

I'm currently working with the CHILDES corpus trying to create a classifier that distinguishes children whom suffer from specific language impairment (SLI) from those who are typically developing (TD).

In my readings I noticed that there really isn't a convincing set of features to distinguish the two that have been discovered yet, so I came upon the crazy idea of trying to create a feature learning algorithm that could potentially make better ones.

Is this possible? If so how do you suggest I approach this? From the reading I have done, most feature learning is done on image processing. Another problem is the dataset I have is potentially too small to make it work (in the 100's) unless I find a way to get more transcripts from children.

Answer (score 2):

Create a dataset consisting of children text with three labels:
1- Normal
2- SLI
3- TD

So you'll have 3 labels.

You put aside 40% of your dataset 20% for development and 20% for test.

Then you run a LogisticRegression Classifier (e.g. using scikit-learn) using bag of character n-gram features. You can easily do this by TfidfVectorizer in scikit-learn.

Then you train the model over the 60% training set and you tune the hyper-parameters (e.g. regularization strength) by choosing the best performing development model.

Then, you train again using the chosen hyper-parameters and you get the top important features as in this [example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/text/document_classification_20newsgroups.html).

For each class, it gives you the weight of features associated with each label so you'll have your top linguistic symptoms for each of your two diseases.